# RequireJS & Gulp - how to append "?v=..." on minified main.js

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, gulp, minify

I have a problem creating minified main.js with version prefix. I've tried to use `urlAgrs`, but it didn't work. Here some code:

`main.js`:

```
(function () {
    require.config({

        // urlAgrs: 'v='+(new Date()).getTime(), // Dev purposes.
        urlAgrs: 'v=1', // Production purposes.

        paths: {
            'angular': 'bower_components/angular/angular',
            'jquery': 'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery',
            ...
        },
        shim: {
            'angular': {
                deps: ['jquery'],
                exports: 'angular'
            },
            ...
    });

    require([
            'angular',
            ...
        ],
        function (angular) {
            ...
        });
})();
```

`gulpfie.js`:

```
// Include gulp
var gulp = require('gulp');
var amdOptimize = require('amd-optimize');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

var config = {
    bowerDir: 'bower_components'
};

// Concatenate & Minify JS
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src([
        // Lib JavaScript
        config.bowerDir + '/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
        config.bowerDir + '/angular/angular.js',
        ...

        // App JavaScript
        './app.js',
        './main.js',
        ...
    ])
        .pipe(amdOptimize('main', {configFile: 'main.js'}))
        .pipe(concat('main.js'))
        .pipe(rename('main.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/scripts'));
});

...

gulp.task('default', [
    'scripts',
    ...
]);
```

I want to point out that this is a working project and everything is working fine. I end up with minified `main.js` file in the `dist/scripts` folder which I can use and the project still works. What I want is, to have `main.js?v=1` or `main.js?v=1412412535252` depending on what I've uncommented in `main.js`. 

How this can be achieved? Is the problem in the `gulpfile.js` or somewhere else?